# How many components does the complement of a connected compact set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ have?

Tags: general-topology

How many components of complement of a compact and connected set in $\mathbb{R^2}$has?

Are there any tricks to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complement of a compact, connected set in $\Bbb R^2$ can have any finite number of components, and it can also have countably infinitely many components. The complement of a line segment has one component. The complement of a circle has two. The complement of a figure $8$ has three. By adjoining more and more circles, you can get any finite number. Finally, if you take the union of circles of radius $\frac1n$ and centre $\left\langle\frac1n,0\right\rangle$, you get a compact, connected set whose complement has infinitely many components.

Comment: This Q appeared on my feed today. You didn't mention that the complement, being open in $\Bbb R^2$, cannot have uncountably many components.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I enumerated the possible values.

Comment: The reason why only at most countably many components can happen is that since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is locally connected, all components of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are open, and since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is separable, the disjoint family of open sets admits an injection into a countable set.

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything.  Consider a closed disc with $n$ separated open discs deleted from it.  Such a set is closed and bounded, hence compact; it is clearly connected.  But its complement has $n+1$ connected components.